# How to detect from script when the user's desktop is loaded?

Tags: bash, scripting, desktop, session

I have a daemon, implemented in bash and running by means of `cron` and the `@reboot` option, that shows the desktop in inactivity.
The script is as following (timings are short for testing purposes):

```
#!/bin/bash
P_STATE=0
while :
do
    sleep 5
    if [ $P_STATE == 0 ]; then
         [ `xprintidle` -ge 25000 ] && P_STATE=1 && wmctrl -k on
    else
         [ `xprintidle` -le 25000 ] && P_STATE=0
done
```

Problem: If a user is still, for example, in the login screen, `xprintidle` and `wmctrl` fails since the desktop isn't yet loaded.
In order to avoid this, I've put the next lines at the very beginning of the script:

```
while:
do
    sleep 10s
    [ -n `who | grep "$USER"` ] && break
done
```

So, the script waits the user (the USER variable is set to my user-name in the crontab file) is logged. But, it a user begins, for example, a terminal session (and not a graphical session like KDE or GNOME), the script also continue.

How can I determine if a user is already in a "graphical" session capable of "showing desktop mode" or not? And moreover, how can I ensure that a "graphical" session is completely loaded and not in process of loading or something like that?

**My solution:**
My (informal) solution is adding in the main loop the `grep` line:

```
WAIT_TIME=180

while:
do
    sleep $WAIT_TIME

    [ ! -n "`ps -ef | grep "$WM_CMD" | grep -v "grep"`" ] && continue

    ## My actions here
done
```

Being "$WM_CMD" the target *windows manager command*. I assume that, if the *windows manager command* is running in the system, it means the desktop is completely loaded and any "graphic" command is sure.

Where is WM_CMD variable defined? In the `crontab` line:

```
 @reboot DISPLAY=:0 WM_CMD=/usr/bin/gnome-shell exec script_path/myscript.sh &> /dev/null
```

But also I think that it would be possible to detect the "windows manager command" by means of other system requests. However, for me defining WM_CMD in the crontab file is enough.

Comment: What login manager are you using?

Comment: My login manager is `lightdm`

Comment: [This Super User question](http://superuser.com/questions/121261/how-can-i-set-environment-variables-for-a-graphical-login-on-linux) might be of help to you. I'm not sure it will answer your question completely though.

Comment: It's not particularly robust, but you could check for the Gnome/KDE process...

Comment: @jasonwryan So I've done it finally.

Comment: Other possibility is trying to do a "graphical action" (for example, show the desktop) until this action finishes succesfully (the command return 0)

Comment: You should document what you did as an answer; it may assist others.

Comment: @jasonwryan Done. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: No, I meant add it as an *answer* to your question: that is quite acceptable SE practice. You can even accept it if you like :)

Comment: this question is obtuse and hard to follow, as all the moving parts are broken up into many sections, but you often remind the reader that you've "added this to my script." i'm currently not sure which bits are relevant to what part of whose script. the final result of your script, as one piece, would be preferable for the purpose of determining where the logic goes sour, perhaps with in-line `# comments`.

Comment: Why is it such a problem if `wmctrl` fails? Just let it fail. A fail in this case means it didn't do anything ... which is not bad in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use D-Bus to query session information from `logind` service. It has `org.freedesktop.login1.Manager` interface with several signal like `SessionNew` and `SeatNew`. `org.freedesktop.login1.Seat` and `org.freedesktop.login1.User` interfaces. It can help to get Session/Seat/User state.

Answer (score 1):

Use login session startup script `~/.xprofile` to create some flag file for you. Be it `~/.xlogin_flag`, then in your other script use `inotifywatch` from package `inotify-tools` to see it being created, touched or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Check output of `w` command. You will see login type (X display) in LOGIN@ field.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way to check if a user is connected in X11 is to check for processes that write to `$HOME/.xsession-errors` since when you login graphically, all you stderr is redirected there.

Otherwise just use the `w` command, as already suggested by @Grzegorz: if the `FROM` column starts with `:` then it is a graphical session.

Answer (score 0):

Check in lightdm's runtime directory.  On Arch with systemd and lightdm, when a user logs in, an xauthority file gets created.

```
$ whoami
carl
$ sudo ls -al /run/lightdm/carl
total 4
drwx------ 2 carl    carl     60 Dec 11 19:40 .
drwx--x--x 8 lightdm lightdm 160 Dec 11 19:40 ..
-rw------- 1 carl    carl     55 Dec 11 19:40 xauthority
```

You could test for this with something like this in your while loop.

```
[[ -f /run/lightdm/${USER}/xauthority ]] && continue
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using **systemd**, you can interact with [`logind`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/) via D-Bus.

There's also a utility for that, [`loginctl`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html).

So you do something simple like:

```
if [ -n "`loginctl | grep seat0`" ]; then
    ## user is logged in ##
fi
```

Also, instead of polling, you can wait on a `SessionNew` D-Bus signal

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do [[ $line == *"SessionNew"* ]] && break; done < \
<(dbus-monitor --system "type=signal,interface=org.freedesktop.login1.Manager,member=SessionNew")

# user session has started ...
```